# problemas numero fuera de las comillas php

Tags: php

hola tengo un problema es que estoy haciendo select dinamico y el problema es que al generarse las options del select los numeros se quedan afuera de las comillas y no se como arreglarlo

la primera foto es del error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui esta el codigo que genera el select con las options:

```
   <?php 
    $cluster=$_POST['cluster'];

    $sql="SELECT id_perfil 
        from cluster 
        where id_cluster=$cluster";

    $result=mysql_query($sql, $conexion);
    #echo $result;
    $cadena=" <select id='perfil' name='perfil' class='demo-category'>";
    while ($ver=mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
        #echo $ver[0];
        $cadena=$cadena."<option value=".$ver[0].">".$ver[0]."</option>";
    }

    echo  $cadena."</select>";
    ?>
```

y este es el codigo principal que llama al anterior:

```
<div id="perfil" name="perfil" class="demo-category"></div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $('#cluster').val(1);
                        recargarLista();
                
                        $('#cluster').change(function(){
                            recargarLista();
                        });
                    })
                </script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function recargarLista(){
                        $.ajax({
                            type:"POST",
                            url:"datos.php",
                            data:"cluster=" + $('#cluster').val(),
                            success:function(r){
                                $('#perfil').html(r);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                </script>
```

Comment: Saludos. Mientras llega alguien prueba cambiar **$cadena=$cadena."<option value=".$ver[0].">".$ver[0]."</option>";** por **$cadena=$cadena."<option value='".$ver[0]."'>".$ver[0]."</option>";**; básicamentes es poner el delimitador de la propiedad **value** en este caso te sugiero comillas simple o usando la diagonal pongas las doble comillas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes un error en la salida de $cadena al usar las comillas, yo te recomienda usar siempre un tipo de comillas para el contenido de las variables y otras para el HTML, escribiría la salida así:

```
$cadena=$cadena.'<option value="'.$ver[0].'">"'.$ver[0].'"</option>';
```

De esta forma entiende que las comillas dobles son parte del HTML y luego con comilla simple y punto vas concatenando el valor. De esta forma te debería funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Si sigues el [estandar HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) resuelves el problema fácil

```
<select name="select">
  <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
  <option value="value2" selected>Value 2</option>
  <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

Con ese concepto, ya solo es cuestión de aplicarlo. Puedes usar (1) comillas simples afuera y concatenando con punto o (2) comillas doble usando el caracter escape para poder usarlas dentro, como a continuación:

```
$cadena = '<select id="perfil" name="perfil" class="demo-category">'.PHP_EOL;
while ($ver=mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    #echo $ver[0];
    $cadena = $cadena . "<option value=\"$ver[0]\">$ver[0]</option>".PHP_EOL;
}
echo $cadena."</select>" . PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

tu variable cadena:

```
    $cadena=$cadena."<option value=".$ver[0].">".$ver[0]."</option>";
```

No esta concatenando ninguna comilla doble en la parte de value, así que tu output seguramente esta escribiendo algo como:

```
    <option value=Perfil 1>Perfil 1</option>
```

La imagen que mostraste parece ser del editor del chrome que esta buscando arreglar tu código HTML y por eso está mostrando comillas.

Busca cambiar la parte de asignar la variable $cadena así:

```
    $cadena=$cadena."<option value=\"".$ver[0]."\">".$ver[0]."</option>";
```